# Prepend error message in correct area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery Validation for the error messages and cannot get them to show in the correct place. At present they are defaulted to show after the input field element. I would like the element to show in between the label and the input field.

Current

```
<p>
   <label>Outside Comms:</label><br>    
   <textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="outsideComms"></textarea>
   <div class="error">This is the error message</div>
</p>
```

Ideal

```
<p>
   <label>Outside Comms:</label><br>
   <div class="error">This is the error message</div>    
   <textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="outsideComms"></textarea>
</p>
```

In the errorPlacement I have the below but it's not working. Everything I try either puts it before the label or after the input field but not in between. How can I tell it to put it in after the firstchild of the parent?

```
error.prependTo( element.before );
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And which one of the elements is `element` in your code ?

Comment: Sorry should of been clearer there. The Jquery validation generates that div container with the error message. Element I believe is the input field as that is what it's validating. That's what I've been going on.

Comment: @adeneo The documentation is here http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#options which confirms that the 'element' is in fact the field

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe it's taken me so long to do this... After about 50 uploads the below worked for me.

```
error.insertBefore( element );
```

Answer (score -1):

Hears how I do it:

```
jQuery( "#formID" ).validate({

   rules: {
       grossSalary: { required: true, digits: true, max: 9999999}
   },
   messages: {
       grossSalary: { required: "Please enter a value", digits: "Please enter a whole number", max: "Please enter a maxiumum amount of &pound;9,999,999"}
   },
   errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        element.next('.vError').remove();
        element.after('<div class="vError"><span class="arrow"></span>'
                + error.html() + '</div>');
    },
    success: function(error, element) {
        jQuery(element).next().remove();
   }
});
```

This places the error *after* the input. So I did a little investigation and came up with the following:

```
jQuery( "#itcForm" ).validate({

   rules: {
       grossSalary: { required: true, digits: true, max: 9999999}
   },
   messages: {
       grossSalary: { required: "Please enter a value", digits: "Please enter a whole number", max: "Please enter a maxiumum amount of &pound;9,999,999"}
   },
   errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
        element.prev('.vError').remove();
        element.before('<div class="vError"><span class="arrow"></span>'
                + error.html() + '</div>');
    },
    success: function(error, element) {
        jQuery(element).prev().remove();
   }
});
```

Basically swap 'after' with 'before' and (if required) 'next' with 'prev'...
This places the error message *before* the input element.

As a footnote, I add a style of 'position: relative' to the containing div and 'position: absolute' to .vError. In that way it doesn't matter where the error appears you can position it relative to the containers content...